# Running subprocess in gunicorn without ssh shell leads to 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I try around a bit with flask in python3.4
I got some problems when running my application with gunicorn behind nginx and close my ssh session
After logging in with ssh i run following:

```
gunicorn -w 3 -n MultiServer -b 127.0.0.1:8081 app:app &
```

All works fine as long i am in my ssh session. After i close it, my site is still reachable, but as soon i hit following function:

```
def get_audio(self, a_link, a_format="mp3"):
    a_name = str(self._tmpDownloadDir + "/%(title)s.%(ext)s")
    ex = 'youtube-dl -o "'+ a_name +'" --no-playlist --extract-audio --audio-format '+ a_format + ' "' + a_link + '"'
    if subprocess.call(ex, shell=True) == 0:
        a_name = self._moveAudio()
        return (a_link, a_name, a_format)
    else:
        raise UnsuportedFormatException
```

i got an Internal Server Error. All other sites and functions are working correctly.

Here is the full code:

[MultiServer](https://github.com/Speedy1991/Speedys_Stuff/tree/master/MultiServer)

especially:
[YoutubeService](https://github.com/Speedy1991/Speedys_Stuff/tree/master/MultiServer/MultiServer/services)

As mentioned, as long i am logged in with ssh, all is running fine... and i also set shell=True.

---

UPDATE:

Ok i tried it with this in my app.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    handler = logging.FileHandler('/tmp/app.log')                             
    handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR) 
    app.logger.addHandler(handler) 
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

But log stays empty and no debug occures

Also fixed the gunicorn log:

```
gunicorn --error-logfile /tmp/app1.log -w 3 -n MultiServer -b 127.0.0.1:8081 app:app &
```

Its also empty, just some Infos about workers started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After logging in with ssh i run following:
>
> ```
> gunicorn -w 3 -n MultiServer -b 127.0.0.1:8081 app:app &
> ```
>
> All works fine as long i am in my ssh session. After i close it, my site is still reachable, but ...

You can't run gunicorn like that. It is part of your ssh session and it is killed when you log out (in particular, it loses its controlling terminal and gets SIGHUPped).

You can work around this by having gunicorn background itself better by using the `--daemon` flag, but you should really consider running gunicorn from a proper process control system such as *systemd* or *supervisor*.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. I tried deamon + supervisor, both runs  perfectly nice :)

Comment: @Speedy, with supervisor (as with most process control systems) it's better _not_ to use `--daemon`. Daemonizing detaches gunicorn from its parent process (which is why it'd help on the command line), which means supervisor can't easily track if gunicorn is still running.

Comment: yes that was exactly what i mean, i did 2 trys: one with gunicorn and --deamon and one with supervisor + gunicorn (without deamon). Maybe my first comment leads to missunderstanding. But both ways works, and i'm running it with supervisor now.